# Java - Changing from a + or - calculation depending on user input

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Creating a caeser cipher using java (a program which  moves characters up or down the alphabet to encrypt or decrypt). To encryp/decrypt the program should either + or - by a number. I have got the program working to add but I was wondering if there was a way of simply changing the calculator action from + to - if the user has selected encrypt or decrypt.

Here's the code:

```
        number = number + offsetInput;
        messageArray[i] = (char) number;
```

Prior to this piece of code the user has entered either 'e' to encrypt or 'd' to decrypt, is there a way to make it so that the +/- changes depending on this input? I know how you would do it if the +/- was a `String` however, it obviously isn't a String. If my idea could be done, it would mean my program could be shorter and not need two separate possible calculations on `if` statements.

Comment: add a variable that is 1 or -1 depending on the selection of encode or decode.  Then multiply what you are adding or subtracting from the character by that value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to solve this. The most simple, I think is to do the following:

```
number = number + offset * multiple;
```

where

```
multiple = input.equals("e") ? 1 : -1;
```

The ternary operator used here means that if the input is 'e', we increment, otherwise, decrement by the offset. We could also write

```
multiple = input.equals("e") ? 1 : input.equals("d") ? -1 : 0;
```

for input validation

Comment: I didn't even think of multiplying by either 1 or -1, that's a fairly easy solution, hats off to you! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
if (input.equals("d")) {
    offsetInput = - offsetInput;
}
```

before the loop.  This is assuming `input` is a `String`.  If it's a `char`, then it should be

```
if (input == 'd') {
```